# Use .filter with array of dictionaries in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have an array called `master` and it is of type `Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()`. I am trying to use the filter function, like this:

```
filteredMusic = allSongNames.filter({ (song: String) -> Bool in
    let stringMatch = song.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
    return stringMatch != nil
})
```

Where `filteredMusic` and `allSongNames` are both arrays of String. I try to translate this with my `master` array, and `masterFilter` (same type as `master`):

```
masterFilter = master.filter({ (song: String, id: String) -> Bool in
    let stringMatch = song.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
    return stringMatch != nil
})
```

My error:

```
'(String, String) -> Bool' is not convertible to '([String : String]) -> Bool'
```

I must be messing up syntax. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Your desired result is... an array of dictionaries of (song,id) where one entry in the dictionary has the desired searchText?  That does't sound very useful.  I'd think that you want an array of (song,id)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your filter's closure, you're accepting two `String` parameters, but you must accept a single `[String:String]` instead (i.e, the type that your array contains: `Dictionary<String, String>`). Therefore, you need to change your filter to something like…

```
masterFilter = master.filter({ (dictionary: [String:String]) -> Bool in
    …
})
```

Because your filter is now accepting a dictionary instead of two strings, you need to change how it works. Presumably you'll want to iterate through the dictionary performing a search, but the exact implementation depends on what you're trying to acheive. An example might be:

```
masterFilter = master.filter({ (dictionary: [String:String]) -> Bool in
    for (song, id) in dictionary {
        if song.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The type signature of Array's `filter` instance method is

```
func filter(includeElement: (T) -> Bool) -> [T]
```

Which means that it takes a function that takes an argument of type `T` and returns `true` or `false` and the filter instance methods returns an array of type `T` which is the same type as the function's parameter given to it.

Your first use of `filter` works because it's an array of `String` data types though the second doesn't work because `(song: String, id: String)` implies that there's a function with two parameters given to `filter`. The error generated by compiler fully describes it. It says the type is a dictionary thus [String : String]. So, in order to make it work you should do it in this way:

Remember that `Dictionary` data type has an instance variable called `keys` which returns a value of type `LazyForwardCollection<MapCollectionView<[Key : Value], Key>>`. The definition is

```
var keys: LazyForwardCollection<MapCollectionView<[Key : Value], Key>> { get }
```

`LazyForwardCollection` has an instance variable `first` which gives you the first element, it also has `array` which gives you all the elements.

```
var first: S.Generator.Element? { get }

// Let the compiler infer the type though you can give (dict: [String : String]) -> Bool
masterFilter = master.filter { dict in 
        let song = dict.keys.first

        let stringMatch = song.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        return stringMatch != nil
    }
```

I didn't use for-in loop because the way your code showed(though it didn't compile) me, it just has one key/value pair in dictionaries inside the array. Although you can use it if there's a need.

You also didn't use `id`. So it seems to me that you don't need the values, though the nature of dictionary is that you need both keys and values otherwise Array data type would work. One possible guess is that you're retrieving the data from a web server that returns a JSON or other notations so you first cast it to dictionary then use it.